# TeamCity and Path to srcsafe.ini

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, teamcity

I am trying TeamCity as an alternative to CruiseControl.NET at the moment. However, I'm having real trouble with using it with Visual Sourcesafe (I know we'll be moving off this in near future!).

However in the VSS Settings in the "Path to srcsafe.ini" field I am getting the following error when I click on Test Connection:

Error: File does not exist. Please check TeamCity server user account has enough rights to access the path

I am running TeamCity in local machine/user account.  The path to the file IS available if I put it into explorer url bar like so:

\\sourcesafe\source safe\AHV_RSLManager\srcsafe.ini

I copied this into the field and no luck. Tried removing the filename, slashes, but no luck so far! Fustrating to say the least as TeamCity looks to be a nicer, easier to use system then CC.NET.  But at the moment it doesn't want to work!!

So what is going on with this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you run TeamCity as a service or as normal application from the command line as logged in user? Local services do not have access to the UNC paths.

Comment: As a service I think. I've not started the app from command line so I guess it is.  If it is a service, does that rule out UNC paths altogether? Seems a little strange that the service won't allow network paths. How else am I supposed to connect to the sourcesafe server?

Comment: It may help if you change the service account from the default Local SYSTEM to NETWORK SERVICE account and restart the service. If it doesn't help, put a copy of the file on the server machine and specify the local path in the settings.

Comment: I tried making the BuildAgent and WebService both run as NETWORK SERVICE, but when I browse to TC admin site I'm now getting failed to connect to DB server error etc...something about lock files.

Not sure what I'm doing here, I think I'm out of my depth. I thought it would be as simple as point the TC server at the source safe path. It seems now the whole thing is corrupted.

Comment: By default TeamCity data directory is placed under user profile directory. If you've changed the user, then you need to ensure that either the same directory is used or copy the directory to the new location. Also check the file permissions, they must be valid for the new user account. See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/TeamCity+Data+Directory.

Comment: I might try and revisit this. I gave up in the end! Think I'll just go back to CruiseControl.NET as this seems to work out of the box and I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Posting this for people looking for a solution today. I got this working by installing teamcity on the same server as sourcesafe. Looks like this is the only way since sourcesafe has lot of permission constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. We changed both team city services to "network services" on the box, added Network Services to the local administrators group, restarted the services multiple times in different orders (including the "server" service, and then it finally worked!

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but granting Network Service local administrator rights is a substantial security risk; you should think twice and consult Google before doing it on a private network, let alone a production server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been setting this up in our environment so I'll share some discoveries in case they're of use to someone else.

The VSS integration is a little feature-light compared to the other VCS integrations:

1. There's no agent checkout, and
2. There's no option to access the share as an account other than the account that the TeamCity Server is running as.

Practically, I think #2 is what's causing you issues.  There are a couple of possible solutions.

In our environment we've got an Active Directory to which both the TC Server and the VSS fileshare server are joined, so we can just run the TC Server service as a domain account (which will need specific permissions, see [the TC documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-installingViaExecutable)) and grant that domain account access to the VSS fileshare.

If you don't have an Active Directory, you might be able to use pass-through authentication by creating local accounts at both ends with the same password.  Arguably this is a security hold, so with recent versions of Windows (post-2003?) there is a group policy setting needed to allow it.  I'm a bit rusty on the details, and not sure whether it's even possible with current Windows, but it might be worth a look.